# Is it correct to return a 502 status code when it's my proxy that has an internal error?

Tags: http, proxy, rfc, rfc2616

I've written a small proxy, and I'm wondering if it's correct for me to return a `502 Bad Gateway` error when the proxy server itself has an internal error. The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) seem to say that this is something you only do if the server on the other end gives a bad response.

> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.

I take this to mean that if for example the upstream server is setting a `content-length` header that is different from the response body length, we should set a `502` error i.e. when the response is invalid.

Am I misinterpreting the RFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An invalid Content-Length could just as well be handled as an invalid response (502 error). 503 should only be used when the condition is temporary, i.e., the same request can be served at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to use 500 AFAIK. This is in a way wrong, as there's no distinction between the origin server and the proxy. I've also observed servers returning 504, but I consider this behavior wrong.